# Finding the specific id and class of text field and document.write it

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  <input type='text' class='key' id='23' value=''>
  <input type='text' class='key' id='24' value=''>
  <input type='text' class='key' id='23' value=''>
```

Is it possible to look up the text field who has the specific class and ID i want and `document.write` a variable for its value?

Like for example:

I have: `var hello ='test'`
I want to input a value of var hello to the text field who has `class='key'` and `id='23'`.

then do   `html(hello)` for it to input the value of hello

Hope anyone can help me.
Still learning js

Comment: What JS code have you tried so far?

Comment: still learning the jquery and how ajax works. @QuentinVeron Thanks for reaching out!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by getting the id of particular element.

```js
var hello = 'hello';
document.getElementById('23').value = hello
```

```html
<input type='text' class='key' id='23' value=''>
<input type='text' class='key' id='24' value=''>
<input type='text' class='key' id='23' value=''>
```

there are many others like

```
document.getElementsByName()
document.getElementsByTagName()
document.getElementsByClassName()
```

[get HTML Elements](http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html)

The difference between id and others is Id is always unique so ypu get a unique result but in others you will get an array so can get the value through index  like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class')[0].value
```

Comment: Helpful way thankyou but Im looking for something that finds class name and Id name at the same time. But I really appreciate it tho thankss

Comment: @Taylor you can get that also first get the tag name then id